# Do this series of functions converge uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, cauchy-sequences

The series of functions $\{f_n\}$ is given by $$f_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2^k}{z^k+z^{-k}} \quad \text{for } |z|<\frac{1}{2}.$$

The exercise given to me is to show that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly.

My attempt:

\begin{align}
|f_n-f_m|\leq |\sum_{k=m}^{n}\frac{2^k}{z^k+z^{-k}}| \leq\sum_{k=m}^{n}\frac{2^k}{|z^k+z^{-k}|} 
\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\|f_n-f_m\| \leq \Big\| \sum_{k=m}^{n}\frac{2^k}{|z^k+z^{-k}|} \Big\|.
\end{align}
The sum is biggest for $|z^k+z^{-k}|$ smallest. If we consider the function $g(z)=z^k+z^{-k}$ we see that  it is holomorphic on $D(0,\frac{1}{2})$ except for $z=0$. Thus the maximum has to occur on the boundary. Moreover $|g|$ has a lower bound $=\frac{1}{2^k}+2^k$. However, doing this gets us
\begin{align}
\|f_n-f_m\| \leq  \sum_{k=m}^{n}\frac{2^k}{2^k+2^{-k}} .
\end{align}

which is obviously not Cauchy for $k,m>N$ for sufficiently large $N$.

**My Question:** Are the series of functions uniformly convergent and if yes can I have a **hint** as how to approach this?

Comment: It's not true that $|g(z)|\ge 2^k+1/2^k$. The triangle inequality shows that $|g(z)|\ge 2^k-1/2^k$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you for the comment. If one was to use the triangle inequality wouldn't one get $|g(z)| \leq  |z^n| +|z^{-n}| rather than what you have? Moreover, I didn't use the triangle inequality because I do not want an upper bound, but rather a lower.

Comment: Well how _did_ you obtain $|g(z)|\ge 2^k+1/2^k$??? For a correct lower bound, note that $|a|=|(a+b)-b|\le|a+b|+|b|$, hence $|a+b|\ge|a|-|b|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I see my mistake now. I would like to further ask now that you have helped me understand that $|g(z)| \geq 2^k -1/2^k$ I still get that the series are not uniformly convergent. Do you know how I can proceed to prove that they are?

Comment: What makes you think the series is uniformly convergent? My conjecture is that the exercise actually asked you to show it's uniformly convergent _on_ compact _subsets_ of $D(0,1/2)$ (Hint: If the sum converged uniformly the sum would be uniformly continuous on $D(0,1/2)$, and hence it would extend continuously to the closure...)